# Remove first and last character in string

Tags: php

A question about php.

If I have variable named $string that contains the word `"Testing"` I would like the php
code to delete the first and last character. (So the output would be `"estin"`).
I've tried multiple functions for example `str_replace` and `substr` but so far I've only managed to delete only the first or only the last character.

I don't know how to delete both the first and last character.

Comment: if you delete the first and last character, the output must be 'estin'

Answer (score 12):

```
<?php
$str = 'Testing';
$result = substr($str, 1, -1);
echo $result; // estin
```

#### the result of the code: http://codepad.org/RLbw4azA

#### read more about: [substr](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php)

---

function: `substr` can receive 3 parameters:

```
    string substr (string $string , int $start [, int $length ] )
```

If ***length*** is given and is **negative**, then that many characters will be omitted from the end of string (after the start position has been calculated when a start is negative). If start denotes the position of this truncation or beyond, false will be returned.

Answer (score 4):

use preg_replace

```
$string = preg_replace('/^.|.$/','',$string);
```

Comment: This is the right answer which gives option to replace a character and not just removing.

Answer (score 3):

```
$str = "Testing";
echo $str = substr($str,1,-1);
```

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried this:

```
$string = substr($string, 1, -1);
```

Answer (score 2):

try `substr($string, 1, -1)`. It will help

Answer (score 1):

$str = 'ABCDEFGH';

echo $result = substr($str, 1, -1);

//output will be show the BCDEFG

Comment: we desperately needed one more `substr($str, 1, -1)` answer...